# Python: How do I define a custom data type for a float that is not NaN or Infinity?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to be able to enforce an argument given to a function to be a float that is not NaN or Infinity and do it in a clean way.

Like this:

```
def f(x: NumberFloat):
    assert isinstance(x, NumberFloat)
    ...
```

I guess, I need to define my own class. But how exactly?

Or maybe I can make a decorator for the function?

Comment: Wait, you tagged this with type hinting. What are you *actually trying to do*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, in this particular case it's just a hint. But I've recently started using Pydantic for type checking at runtime. It would be nice to check if arguments follow certain rules through type hinting and not make my functions bloated with assert statements.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use math.[isfinite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isfinite). The function is True if the given number is finite which excludes `NaN`  and `inf`. In all this please note that in Python it is better to ask for forgiveness than permission. So check the input only if really required.

Comment: No, involving numpy doesn't make any sense, OP would want `math.isfinite` unless they are specifically working with `numpy`

Comment: Fair point. Will edit my answer to use math.isfinite

Answer (score 1):

I probably misunderstood your question, but check this out and let me know

```py
class ocean(float):    
    def __init__(self, float_element):  
        if(type(float_element) == str):
            if(float_element.lower() == 'inf' or float_element.lower() == 'nan'):    
                raise ValueError(f"ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{float_element}'")
        super().__init__()    
    
infinity = ocean('inf')
```

All the `float` operations will work in `ocean`. But `inf` and `nan` are filtered and cause `ValueError`, the same error raised when using an invalid float in `float`

Comment: I don't think you can just assume `.lower` will exist on `float_element`, anything can be passed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes. I have to check that `float_element` is a string type first